# IE Strips Formfeed Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

It appears as though IE6, IE7, and IE8 are stripping \f (formfeed) characters from the end of plain text ajax requests. I am using jQuery to request a plain text "page" of text from the server. I attempt to replace the \f characters in the response (before inserting into the DOM) and in legacy IE browsers the \f character is not present. If I add a \f character to the data string it is replaced as expected. Also, just for reference, not all "pages" returned will have a \f character at the end. This is why I can not just manually insert the \f character. Is there an IE6-8 limitation I am missing?

```
        var results = "";   

        $.ajax(
            {
            url: c,
            dataType: "text",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(data)
                {
                var start = data.indexOf("PAGEMETADATA");
                if  (start > 0)
                    {
                    nextnoteid = data.substring(start + 20, start + 36);
                    alert(nextnoteid);
                    data = data.substring(0, start - 4);
                    }
                results += data;
                }
            });

        $("#pxprintarea").html("<pre>" + results.replace(/\f/gi, "</pre><div class='pxprintpagebreak'></div><pre>") + "</pre>");
```

The type of data that I expect back would look something like this:

Line1\r\n
Line2 asdf asdf asdf\r\n
\r\n
------------------------------------\r\n
End of page\f

Comment: What is the content-type of your response?

Comment: Have you looked at the response and see what is being returned? Use `unescape(data)` to see the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE6-8 will terminate the response on the 0x00 (null) character.